# C++ glfw3: one (of the two) windows in fullscreen mode is not really fullscreen (Mac Os)

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw

In my app (C++14, MacOsX 10.11) I use glfw3 to create two windows that should run in fullscreen mode in two monitors with different native resolutions. I'm creating the windows like this:

```
 glfwCreateWindow(capture_monitor_width, capture_monitor_height, "Capture Window",capture_monitor,NULL);
//.. 
glfwCreateWindow(projection_monitor_width, projection_monitor_height, "Projection Window",projection_monitor,NULL).
```

(where `projection_motinor_width`, `projection_monitor_height`,`capture_motinor_width`,`capture_monitor_height` have been retrieved by the appropriate `GLFWvidmode*` and they have been tested to be correct in all cases)

The problem is that while I'm getting the fullscreen window correctly in my primary monitor, in my secondary one it is displaced upwards so that it only covers the upper 3/4 (more or less) of the screen. Note that by simply replacing `projection_monitor`with `NULL` in the snippet above I get a properly aligned window that does cover the entire screen (yet it has a title bar which I don't need in my app).

Any ideas? Could this be some sort of bug? Any hacks around it?

Comment: Since GLFW3 is open-source, you can dive into the source code yourself to see how the window is created.  There's also a GLFW forum, an IRC channel, and you can submit issues to the GitHub project.

Comment: I've already tried the forum/irc. It looks like a bug so maybe you're right, I should open an an issue @ github.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest 'devel' version the problem is no longer there. So apparently it's a bug that has already been fixed.